# How to get first subdomain with RewriteCond htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Consider this URL:

```
www.sub1.sub2.sub3.subdomain.domain.com
```

The only thing that is a given is "domain.com". Now, I want to forward this UGLY url to: subdomain.domain.com. So somehow I have to get the subdomain.

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)/.([^.]+)/.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which won't work, as htaccess doesn't support look behind.

Any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+?\.([^.]+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You are fast and accurate! Thank you! It works perfectly.